# Use batch to make duplicate files based on one extension

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

How can I make copies of some files with a specific extension (but changing the extension) just based on their extension?

I've tried just showing those files but get nothing:

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.ext) do(
  echo %%~nf
)
pause
```

My other option is copy all those and change their extension in a different folder. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: expands %f to a file name only (as documentation explain: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the old DOS days we used this:

```
@echo off

copy *.{ext} {destination path}\*.{new ext}
```

Example:

I wanted to copy all of my sketchup files from a Temp Download folder to a Sketchup_Files folder in my User folder.

I created a text file with the command lines:

```
@echo off

copy *.skp C:\Users\Me\Sketchup_Files\*.txt
```

I saved this file as a .bat and pasted it into my target folder {Temp Download}

Good Luck.

Comment: Ok but how can I copy those files but with different extension, I mean I just care of many file's names and getting those with different extension

Comment: Gotcha, you're question wasn't clear about copying them to a new location with a new file extension. Give me a sec to see what I can remember, there is a command for that.  Ok, I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help it works as expected, hope don't mind for identation added

Answer (score 1):

`for %f in (*.ext) do copy "%~f" "%~nf - Copy%~xf"` will make copies of all files with the specified extension in the same directory with " - Copy" appended just as Windows Explorer does.

If you use it in a batch file remember to double all % signs.

Comment: Thanks @Karan, I've edited my question because I forgot to specify the change of extension I wanted

Comment: @CharlesRojas: I don't get it. If you want to make copies of files with the same name in the same directory but a different extension, all you need to use is `copy *.ext *.newext`. This seems so obvious that I'm unsure whether it's what you want to do or I'm not understanding your requirements properly perhaps.

Comment: Yes, that was what I wanted, just didn't know and I've trying to check by echoing each file

Comment: @CharlesRojas: Oh ok then. Frankly the accepted answer is unnecessarily using two commands when just one will do. I don't know why he's using a separate `ren` command.

Comment: You're right, that would be a better option

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with something like `copy *.ext *.ex2 ?`